# How to get value with an underscore inside a string from Elasticsearch using QueryBuilder in Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 3.2.7 and ElasticsearchRepository.search() which takes QueryBuilder as an argument ([doc](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-elasticsearch/3.2.x/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/ElasticsearchRepository.html#search-org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder-))

I have a BoolQueryBuilder and use it like this:

```
boolQuery.must(termQuery("myObject.code", value);
var results = searchRepository.search(boolQuery);
```

The definition of the field `code` is as follows:

```
"myObject": {
    "properties": {
        "code": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        }
```

The issue is, when I search with a value that has underscore inside, for example: `FOO_BAR` then it doesn't return any results. When I search with other values that have either leading or trailing underscore then it's fine.

I've read that ES may ignore the special character and split the words inside by it so there's a need for an exact match search. But I also read that the `keyword` setting guarantees that. So right now I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you are correct, using `keyword` field you can achieve the exact match, you need to use the below query

```
boolQuery.must(termQuery("myObject.code.keyword", value); --> note addition of keyword
var results = searchRepository.search(boolQuery);
```

you can use the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to see the tokens for your indexed documents and search term, and basically your tokens in index must match search terms tokens, in order ES to return the match :)

Comment: ahhhh, so simple, so elegant, so many times wasted on trying to apply KeywordAnalyzer... thanks :)

Comment: @Kamil, glad I was of help :)